# getting an error 500 internal server in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel

i'm trying to response json with view inside to show the data to my view without refreshing the page

my function in controller:

```
public function addFlight($id)
    {
        session()->forget('ticket');
        
        $flight = $this->flightModel->find($id);

        $ticket = session()->get('ticket');
        $ticket[$id] = [
            'flight_ID' => $id,
            'aircraft_ID' => $flight->aircraft_ID,
            'start_airport_ID' => $flight->start_airport_ID,
            'start_time' => $flight->start_time,
            'arrive_airport_ID' => $flight->arrive_airport_ID,
            'arrive_time' => $flight->arrive_time,
            'price' => $flight->price,
        ];

        session()->put('ticket', $ticket);
        return response()->json([
            'code' => 200,
            'component' => view('client.home.booking_list')->with(['ticket' => session()->get('ticket')])->render(),
        ],200);
    }
```

my ajax function:

```
$('.add_flight').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let url = $(this).data('url');
    let id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url:url,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            if(data.code === 200){
                $('.booking_list').html(data.component);
            }
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error!');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try changing  let url = $(this).data('url')+"/"+ $(this).data('id');

Comment: also alert url see what you get,post route  also in question

Comment: You do `session()->forget('ticket')` then do a `session()->get('ticket')` and proceed to use `$ticket` as an array even  though you know it is null at that point

Comment: @apokryfos i deleted that line but still get that error, it just make the session null then reput data into the session

Comment: @JohnLobo i tried to do what you said, it arlet http://localhost:8000/booking/add-flight/2/undefined then return error

Comment: then its already adding to url so not required to append it .so keep as your code same as in your question.enable eror log and check in developer network tab in bowser what erro it is

Comment: `jquery.js:9631 GET http://localhost:8000/booking/add-flight/2 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery.js:9631
ajax @ jquery.js:9176
(anonymous) @ app.js:110
dispatch @ jquery.js:4641
elemData.handle @ jquery.js:4309`
this is what i get in the console

Comment: check in networrekk so you can see what server response is or just open http://localhost:8000/booking/add-flight/2 in browser and see what erro it is

Comment: @JohnLobo i see many tab here: headers, preview,.. wich tab is the most important?

Comment: oh, it said View [client.home.booking_list] not found. but i dont really understand, the path is right

Comment: you can open link in browser with url http://localhost:8000/booking/add-flight/2 so you can see error directly

Comment: it means view not there in views/client/home/booking_list.blade.php

Comment: wait, im such an idiot :)) the path was wrong

Comment: thankyou very much @JohnLobo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax code works fine .The issue with controller `addFlight` method returning wrong view path

As a Error says

> View [client.home.booking_list] not found.

It means view file not found in the below location

```
views/client/home/booking_list.blade.php
```

.Always enable erorr log while working on so you can see errors.If you are using ajax then you can see server response in network tab of browser.For example below screenshot

[image]